# How to measure acoustic pressure level under water with a hydrophone?

Tags: discrete-signals, python, sound, amplitude, acoustics

this is my first post here and I am also new in signal processing.

Let's say I have a hydrophone with amplifier which is connected to a sound card plugged in to a computer. I gather the sounds to a WAV file every 3 seconds and analyze each file in a Python program. The system is supposed to detect loud events which are dangerous for sea animals.

I would like to know **how to reliably measure acoustic pressure** (loudness?) **of events occuring under water based on WAV data**. I am not sure if I should use exactly the same formulas as measuring SPL in air. I do not have the hydrophone yet so I can not really tell anything about it at this moment, but I am pretty sure the catalog notes of the hydrophone will be available for me when I finally get it.

It would be good enough if the measurement had an error under 5 dB SPL. It does not have to be perfect, I just want it to be relative and adapted to under water characteristics.

**Could the simple measurement be calibrated by shifting measures by single constant in dB?**

I found a similar solution in [Determine Sound Intensity in SPL](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35360/determine-sound-intensity-in-spl). But the problem is I do not know if I will be able to have all the data needed for this, mainly about amplification levels. Would the calibration-like solution be good in this case? How can I do it?

Comment: I doubt you can without knowing any information about the response of the hydrophone, the impedance of the cable, and the specs of the DAC in the soundcard. If you do have information from all of those things, then you can probably get a reasonable estimate.

Answer (score 1):

A hydrophone should come with at least a typical response curve.

The thing to aware of is that that response represents an idealized far field response in an infinite space referenced to an wave of an ideal point source taken at one meter (or yard).

A good reference that covers the conversion of acoustic to electrical energy is

> Horton, Joseph Warren. Fundamentals of sonar. United States Naval
>   Institute, 1959.

but his book is scarce as hen's teeth and requires luck or access to a good University library that collected physics and engineering books from the 1950's.

There are other books on transducers.  Essentially an accurate SPL measurement is a bit more than a hydrophone hooked into a sound card.  The field expedient calibration  method is to use a calibrated source at a known direct path distance at least 100 wavelengths in distance.

In most cases the cable you need is going to be too long for a unamplified transduction signal.  It's best to have the converter at the sensor and send over a digital signal but have weak analog signals close to digital circuitry.

Long cables usually imply higher voltages to minimize resistance losses.  Sharks are attracted to cables that have high voltages so don't be surprised when you see cables offering Kevlar with steel reinforcement.

Ideally access to pressure chambers to test your the water-tight integrity of your hyrophone cable is a very good thing to have if you expect to dangle more than 20 feet and the deeper you go the more important it is to pressure check your set up.

Comment: Aside from that I really wonder the following: acoustsical sound waves on **air** are carried as **compression waves**; air molecules are compressed and decompressed so that the pressure increases and decreases as wave passes a point. Now I wonder what's the nature of underwater acoutical waves considereing that water is virtually an **incompressible** fluid ? How does the pressure wave travel accross water?

Comment: It’s been a long time since I looked at the first principles derivation. It’s probably in Morse but there aren’t any infinitely incompressible materials. There is particle displacement

Comment: I checked the wiki page and it states it as a **pressure wave**... So that **slight** compressibility is accounting for the pressure wave in it... Yet the shear forces required to compress it just a little bit makes me wonder how powerful should the transducer be?

Comment: Well, I’ve seen pictures of one system where each transducer was a little smaller than an old Volkswagen Beetle and the array consisted of a few tens of these dangling in a vertical line. High frequency side scan sonars that look like a torpedo can be easily lifted by 2 men. There are pingers that around the size of a beer can. There are all sorts of sizes. It depends on the application

Comment: never seen one :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. My question was if I should use the same formulas as I would use in air. My second question was what should I do best if I will not be able to find out all parameters of the amplifiers? I still need to do some measurement of the loudness even if I have no parameters.
"The field expedient calibration method is to use a calibrated source at a known direct path distance at least 100 wavelengths in distance." - could you say more about it? I am not sure I understand.

Comment: you didn't write down your equation, so I can't answer that question and what don't you understand?  100 wavelengths is a rule of thumb for knowing you are far enough away to be in the far field.  I assume you know that the speed of sound in water is about 5 times the speed in air.

Comment: Equations from https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35360/determine-sound-intensity-in-spl and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Sound_pressure_level. I assume I take 1 Pa as a reference pressure and everything else is just the same?
If I am correct, a 1 kHz sound would mean a 150 m distance (and the typical frequencies are still lower). It is completely impossible for me as I will be only able to test the system in small pool inside a building (around 3x3 m sized). Like I said, the system does not have to be perfect, I just want to measure legit loudness  with < 5 dB error.

Comment: You can buy reference hydrophones. Calibration is not a DYI project for a non specialist

Comment: No, I can not. The total budget for the project is limited to about $50 plus available hardware (1 or 2 hydrophones with amplifier and underwater speaker). So you are saying calibration is not an option (why?) but can I still stick to the plan A which is use of the mentioned formulas?

Comment: Why? This should be obvious. Again, edit your question to include the specific equation that you are asking about. I will not comment on an equation that I have to chase after

Comment: The technique given by A_A is applicable. The effect of the cable needs to taken into account. The hydrophone should have a sensitivity curve although I don’t know what kind of hydrophone and cable you can purchase for $50. If you want to take a level in a 3 by 3 pool, it will not be correct

Comment: Thanks. I am not purchasing any hydrophone, I will use an available one in few weeks when I get an access to laboratory, but I need to be fully prepared as the access time will be limited to few hours. The hydrophone, cable and dedicated amplifier are already in lab, but I don't know anything about its names or parameters yet. I heard they are just ready to use. My own hardware will be only a soundcard (Audiotrak Prodigy Cube Black Edition) and a computer. I assume the hydrophone will be RESON TC4013 so it's got the cable provided. What is the influence of cable parameters on the measurement?

Comment: Assuming TC4013 and the 6m cable, and the amplifier was matched impedance wise, probably could be neglected but there is an equivalent circuit. Long cables will introduce resistance.  I added a much more recent reference to my answer. The e-book is around $50 but I can read it through my school, perhaps you have some similar accommodation.  The book is comprehensive and is going to be more accurate than I am.  If you can find a copy of Horton that would also be good.